# Unable to run X server on a remote VPS server using xvfb

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, display, xvfb

My app uses the library https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf which requires X server. Here's a workaround:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nxvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf -q $*' > /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
chmod a+x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh
ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf
```

I've installed xvfb via pacman and followed the steps in the link. However, nothing has changed: it still returns an error

```
  wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf
```

===>

```
 "qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0"
```

And

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: According to the repo you linked, they don't need a display server: `wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage are command line tools to render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the QT Webkit rendering engine. These run entirely "headless" and do not require a display or display service.`

Comment: @Sven  how will that "no need" fix my error?

Comment: If the projects website claim they don't need a display server and you still need one, it's likely you are doing something wrong (or better, you use optional functionality that indeed need an display server) and it's a good idea to investigate in this direction...

Comment: @Sven what am I doing if not investigating?

Comment: You are investigating how to get it to run with `xvfb`. I suggested that you shouldn't need it and should investigate how to run it without `xvfb`. These are two very different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run wkhtmltopdf.sh instead of just wkhtmltopdf. Seems like you are calling the original binary instead of the xvfb wrapper you created.

To make sure which one you are running try to run "which wkhtmltopdf".

Comment: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: When you run the sh script by the absolute path you get the same result? Tbh I never used xvfb-run, I always started xvfb manually. I would advise to actually try to start xvfb manually and check for possible errors.

Comment: You may also try to add to your xvfb-run the flag --error-file=/some/path/to/log/file.txt to check any possible errors in xvfb startup.